# pass variable to function in volt template in phalcon

Tags: javascript, twig, phalcon, volt

this is my controller that i pass data to view:
here i pass variable named name:

```
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->assets->addJs('js/script.js');
        $this->view->setVar('name', 'john');
    }
}
```

in my volt file i can use name variable and for example creating heading tag like `{{name}}` and that s fine but one thing that i want is that i want to pass name variable to a js function . while i pass data to from volt to my script . value of name variable in my js file is `undefined`. how can i do that??

```
<div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
<h1 style="color:red;">{{ name }}</h1> //it works
<button onclick="changeLevel(1, 2,{{ name }})" type="submit" class="btn btn-block rounded buttonStyle " id="SendPhone" disabled>تایید شماره</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on  the right track, but you have to think a little bit further.

At this moment you have the following code:

```
<button onclick="changeLevel(1, 2,{{ name }})>Click</button>
```

When running this code through `twig` you get the following output:

```
<button onclick="changeLevel(1, 2, john)>Click</button>
```

This means, you will pass the variable `john` to the function `changeLevel`, but `john` is not a known variable in javascript.

---

So what you actually want to do is to pass the literal string `john`, you can achieve this by enquoting the output, e.g.

```
<button onclick="changeLevel(1, 2,'{{ name }}')>Click</button>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/sztz4l)

Comment: Exactly this, the same should work for volt as well.